# Something confusing about IQueryable<T>.GetEnumerator

Tags: linq, iqueryable

```
public class Query<T> : IQueryable<T> ... 
{
              ... 
   public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator() 
   {
      return((IEnumerable<T>)this.provider.Execute(this.expression)).GetEnumerator();
   }
}

Query<string> someQuery = new Query<string>();
var results1 = someQuery.Select(...).Where(...);

string[] initialSet = { };
var results2 = initialSet.Select(...).Where(...);
```

1. When operating on `initialSet`, Linq-to-object's `Where<T>` returns `WhereEnumerableIterator<T>` and thus `results2`  is of type `WhereEnumerableIterator<T>`. But when operating on `someQuery`, does `Where<T>` operator assign to `results1` an instance retrieved by calling `someQuery.GetEnumerator` or does it also return some custom class?
2. If the latter, when exactly is `someQuery.GetEnumerator` called by `Where` and `Select` operators?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The type of `results2` is just `Enumerable<T>` - the type of the *implementation* that the value of `results2` actually refers to at execution time happens to be `WhereEnumerableIterator<T>`, that's all.

When operating on `someQuery`, it depends what you do with it - the type of the `results1` variable is `IQueryable<T>`, so you *can* use more `Queryable` calls on it.

`someQuery.GetEnumerator()` may *never* be called - it's up to the query provider implementation to work out exactly how to represent the query; it doesn't need to call `GetEnumerator` all the way up the chain like LINQ to Objects typically does.

As for the type of object returned by `Queryable.Where` - again, that's up to the query provider implementation - the difference is that whereas the knowledge is baked into `Enumerable.Where` and can't be replaced, `Queryable.Where` will chain the call through to the query provider.

Comment: Will wrap it up quickly: "someQuery.GetEnumerator() may never be called - it's up to the query provider implementation ..."
Thought I assume when implementing someQuery, we should always call this.Provider.Execute within someQuery.GetEnumerator, just in case query provider implementation does need to call it ( assuming query provider is written by some third party vendor )?

Comment: @user702769: The `IQueryable<T>` implementation is provided *by* the provider - so you wouldn't usually be working with an unknown provider. It's not really clear what you're trying to achieve with these posts - if you want to write your own LINQ provider, I don't think Stack Overflow is really the best resource. You might want to study the implementation of some open source providers such as LINQ to NHibernate.

Comment: Not really trying to write anything, but as a beginner perhaps I have a feeling if I don't understand how certain things work that I may not be able to really make any progress in learning particular technology. Perhaps I'm the only one with this problem, but if I don't know the answer to something, then I'm having hard time to continue learning until I know the answer to that particular question - if that makes any sense

Comment: @user702769: It's good to know how things work to some extent, but I think you're probably trying to go a little *too* deep. Understanding what the Queryable extension methods do (and in particular how they're building up a query expression tree, not executing the query) will already put you head and shoulders over many devs. If you want to go much deeper than that (and deeper than Matt Warren's blog series) then looking at a concrete implementation like NHibernate would be a good approach. It's likely to give you more insight than hypotheticals.

Comment: @user702769: Just to be clear, I'm the last person to criticise curiosity - I just think that beyond a certain point, it's worth looking at concrete examples rather than abstractions.

Comment: "...then looking at a concrete implementation like NHibernate would be a good approach." Nah, I'm more on a dumb side so... But I appreciate your advice

Answer (score 1):

> If the latter, when exactly is someQuery.GetEnumerator called by
>   Where and Select operators?

When the query is enumerated. Hence comes the name.

```
initialSet.Select(...).Where(...);
```

This looks wrong. You use the Where to filter, and the Select to project the result. You appear to have it backwards.

Comment: "This looks wrong." As far as I know, it is a valid statement, assuming we want to filter on a sequence returned by Select and not on the original sequence

Comment: That is true, the question is why would you want to do such a thing? Filtering before the projection saves you the cost of executing the projection.

Comment: If the filter is _dependent_ on a complex projection then it can make sense to project first. Saving the cost of evaluating the same expression twice, once in the filter, and then again in the projection. This is especially true of in-memory, `IEnumerable` processing, but also has applications in `IQueryable` processing where the projection and filter is dependant on the result of a function call. In most cases there are still performance penalties and there should be some sort of filter that can be applied first, but we can trade them off to keep the code readable in some situations.